# Integral of $x^{12}(1-x)^8$

Tags: calculus

Any one have a cute way of doing this integral:

$$\int x^{12}(1-x)^8\,dx$$

I expanded using the binomial theorem, but wondering if their is a easier way?

Comment: Well, if you're feeling particularly good at remembering minus signs you could integrate by parts... There's no nice factorisation for the answer to this sort of thing, so in general the answer is normally not.

Comment: I was going to propose turning it into a "trigonometric powers" integral by using  

$$ \ x \ = \ \sin^2 \theta \ \ , \ \ 1 \ - \ x \ = \ \cos^2 \theta \ \ ,  \ \text{and} \ dx \ = \ \ 2 \ \sin \theta \ \cos \theta \ d\theta \ \ . $$

It follows a reasonably clear reduction formula, but isn't really going to be any less work...

Comment: Tabular looks okay, but I think the binomial thm may be nicer here. Maybe $\int x^4 (x-x^2)^8 dx$ with tabular.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, you could use $x=\sin^2(t)$ which makes $$I=\int x^{12}(1-x)^8\,dx=2 \int \sin ^{25}(t) \cos ^{17}(t)\,dt$$ The most general reduction formula is $$J(p,q)=\int \sin ^{p}(t) \cos ^{q}(t)\,dt=\sin^{p-1}(t)\cos^{q-1}(x)\Big(\sin^2(t)-\frac{q-1}{p+q-2}\Big)+\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{(p+q)(p+q-2)}J(p-2,q-2)$$ but, as already pointed in comments, this will not be helping you much except if you integrate for $x$ between $0$ and $1$ ($t$ between $0$ and $\frac \pi 2$). In such a case, the first term would disappear because of the bounds and the general expression will be $$K(p,q)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \sin ^{p}(t) \cos ^{q}(t)\,dt=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{q+1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{p+q}{2}+1 \right)}$$

For any other case, I suppose that the binomial expansion is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tabular method with $x^{12}$ as your starting $u$ and $(1-x)^8$ as your starting $dv$.

Comment: This is a scheme for repeated integration by parts.  One factor is integrated, the other differentiated in each step.  When you get zero derivative, you are done, and read the answer from the table you created.

Comment: You can substitute $x = sin^2\theta$. The integrand reduces to $sin^{25}\theta cos^{17}\theta$. If the limit of integration is between $0$ and $2\pi$, then the resultant integration gives 0. Otherwise there are standard formulae to find $\int sin^{m}\theta cos^{n}\theta d\theta$